# How could I increase the width of this "row" background without affecting what's on top? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm learning web dev, and I've encountered this puzzle where I can't find a way to increase the **width of the background** of my paragraph text that's next to an image of a cookie, could you help me please?, *I've tried increasing the width but it just rezises the whole thing.*

Here's an image
[image]

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 105px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: -25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#Cookieland {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #49403f;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 55px;
}

.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #49403f;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #49403f;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/*Body section begins here*/

.banner-header {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/GMkdz66/cookiess.jpgg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.8s;
    animation: parallax linear;
    animation-timeline: scroll();
}
.banner-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #92836c;
    opacity: .4;
    z-index: .1;
}

.cookie-heading {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #352000, 2px 2px 4px #352000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.description {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #352000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes parallax {
    to {
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
}

/*Second row begins here*/
.row {
    width: 1000px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 50px 30px;
    background-color: #636363; /*#f6f6f6*/
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.row .left {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row .left img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}
.row .right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.row .right .content {
    padding-left: 20px;

}
.row .right .content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .row .right .content {
        padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        width: 90%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Milk n' Cookies: Buy the best flavoured cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Header sections including navigation bar-->
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.html" id="Cookieland">Milk n' Cookies</a></h1>
       
        <form class="search-container" action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies, flavours, recipes and more.">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
        
    <!--Navigation bar of the header-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--Banner of the header section, it includes an about text with paragraph-->
    <section class="banner-header">
        <h2 class="cookie-heading">About us</h2>
        
        <p><span class="description">Welcome to Milk n' Cookies, where dreams are baked into reality! For over five decades,<br>our company has been delighting taste buds and warming hearts with our delectable array of cookies.</br> Established half a century ago, our journey began with a simple recipe and a passion for spreading joy</br> through irresistible treats. Today, we stand proudly as the epitome of excellence in the culinary world,</br> renowned as the best company globally for our unparalleled dedication to quality, innovation, and customer</br> satisfaction. With each bite of our scrumptious creations, customers embark on a journey of flavor</br> and nostalgia, making Milk n' Cookies  not just a brand but a cherished tradition in homes worldwide.</br> Join us as we continue to redefine sweetness for generations to come.</span></p>
    </section>

        <!--Second section, it includes an image and text-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg" alt="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="content"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus 
                    veritatis praesentium deleniti totam atque, corporis repellat? 
                    Doloremque inventore nostrum rerum nemo ullam assumenda architecto 
                    nesciunt? Nihil vero hic qui? Sequi?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Porro, culpa quasi omnis optio qui totam incidunt soluta quibusdam 
                    harum deleniti ut vel error tempora facere saepe a voluptas rem. Ut?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam velit 
                    itaque tempore a, modi officia, autem, sint laudantium non animi nam 
                    onsequatur laborum aperiam. Culpa voluptatibus laborum natus illo eum.</p>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you could do is to remove the `width: 1000px;` on your `.row` (this is what restricting you)

Make it like this :

```js
.row {
    width: 1000px; //REMOVED
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 50px 30px;
    background-color: #636363;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Now the next thing that you could do is to give your `.row .right` width so his container (the one with the background) will be able to spread and take all the space available but not the texts section itself :

```js
.row .right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
}
```

And it will look like this :

[image]

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 105px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: -25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#Cookieland {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #49403f;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 55px;
}

.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #49403f;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #49403f;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/*Body section begins here*/

.banner-header {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/GMkdz66/cookiess.jpgg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.8s;
    animation: parallax linear;
    animation-timeline: scroll();
}
.banner-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #92836c;
    opacity: .4;
    z-index: .1;
}

.cookie-heading {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #352000, 2px 2px 4px #352000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.description {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #352000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes parallax {
    to {
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
}

/*Second row begins here*/
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 50px 30px;
    background-color: #636363; /*#f6f6f6*/
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.row .left {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row .left img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}
.row .right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40%;
}
.row .right .content {
    padding-left: 20px;

}
.row .right .content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .row .right .content {
        padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        width: 90%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Milk n' Cookies: Buy the best flavoured cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Header sections including navigation bar-->
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.html" id="Cookieland">Milk n' Cookies</a></h1>
       
        <form class="search-container" action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies, flavours, recipes and more.">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
        
    <!--Navigation bar of the header-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--Banner of the header section, it includes an about text with paragraph-->
    <section class="banner-header">
        <h2 class="cookie-heading">About us</h2>
        
        <p><span class="description">Welcome to Milk n' Cookies, where dreams are baked into reality! For over five decades,<br>our company has been delighting taste buds and warming hearts with our delectable array of cookies.</br> Established half a century ago, our journey began with a simple recipe and a passion for spreading joy</br> through irresistible treats. Today, we stand proudly as the epitome of excellence in the culinary world,</br> renowned as the best company globally for our unparalleled dedication to quality, innovation, and customer</br> satisfaction. With each bite of our scrumptious creations, customers embark on a journey of flavor</br> and nostalgia, making Milk n' Cookies  not just a brand but a cherished tradition in homes worldwide.</br> Join us as we continue to redefine sweetness for generations to come.</span></p>
    </section>

        <!--Second section, it includes an image and text-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg" alt="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="content"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus 
                    veritatis praesentium deleniti totam atque, corporis repellat? 
                    Doloremque inventore nostrum rerum nemo ullam assumenda architecto 
                    nesciunt? Nihil vero hic qui? Sequi?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Porro, culpa quasi omnis optio qui totam incidunt soluta quibusdam 
                    harum deleniti ut vel error tempora facere saepe a voluptas rem. Ut?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam velit 
                    itaque tempore a, modi officia, autem, sint laudantium non animi nam 
                    onsequatur laborum aperiam. Culpa voluptatibus laborum natus illo eum.</p>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated your code.

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 105px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin: -25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#Cookieland {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #49403f;
}

body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.search-container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 55px;
}

.search-input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.search-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.search-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #49403f;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #49403f;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/*Body section begins here*/

.banner-header {
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/GMkdz66/cookiess.jpgg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    top: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.8s;
    animation: parallax linear;
    animation-timeline: scroll();
}
.banner-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #92836c;
    opacity: .4;
    z-index: .1;
}

.cookie-heading {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #352000, 2px 2px 4px #352000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.description {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #352000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes parallax {
    to {
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
}

/*Second row begins here*/
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
    gap: 50px 30px;
    background-color: #636363;
}

.left {
    width: 427px; /* you can ajust the width if you want*/
    min-width: 427px; /* you can ajust the max-width if you want*/
    height: 100%;
}

.left img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.right {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Milk n' Cookies: Buy the best flavoured cookies!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Header sections including navigation bar-->
    <header>
        <h1><a href="index.html" id="Cookieland">Milk n' Cookies</a></h1>
       
        <form class="search-container" action="#">
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies, flavours, recipes and more.">
            <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </form>
        
    <!--Navigation bar of the header-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!--Banner of the header section, it includes an about text with paragraph-->
    <section class="banner-header">
        <h2 class="cookie-heading">About us</h2>
        
        <p><span class="description">Welcome to Milk n' Cookies, where dreams are baked into reality! For over five decades,<br>our company has been delighting taste buds and warming hearts with our delectable array of cookies.</br> Established half a century ago, our journey began with a simple recipe and a passion for spreading joy</br> through irresistible treats. Today, we stand proudly as the epitome of excellence in the culinary world,</br> renowned as the best company globally for our unparalleled dedication to quality, innovation, and customer</br> satisfaction. With each bite of our scrumptious creations, customers embark on a journey of flavor</br> and nostalgia, making Milk n' Cookies  not just a brand but a cherished tradition in homes worldwide.</br> Join us as we continue to redefine sweetness for generations to come.</span></p>
    </section>

        <!--Second section, it includes an image and text-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg" alt="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="content"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus 
                    veritatis praesentium deleniti totam atque, corporis repellat? 
                    Doloremque inventore nostrum rerum nemo ullam assumenda architecto 
                    nesciunt? Nihil vero hic qui? Sequi?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                    Porro, culpa quasi omnis optio qui totam incidunt soluta quibusdam 
                    harum deleniti ut vel error tempora facere saepe a voluptas rem. Ut?</p>
    
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam velit 
                    itaque tempore a, modi officia, autem, sint laudantium non animi nam 
                    onsequatur laborum aperiam. Culpa voluptatibus laborum natus illo eum.</p>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup limits the size of your row (which is a grid) to give the cookie a particular size. You should change the individual widths of the elements you don't want stretching to the full bounds of a row.

For the row to cover the whole screen I recommend having the row cover the entirety of the width (setting `.row` 's `width` property to `100%` instead of `1000px`)

After that, define fixed sizes for the column template inside `.row`:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

to

```css
grid-template-columns: xx 1fr;
```

where xx is the fixed size you want the cookie in the row to be (even percentages). After you do that, change your `.row .right .content`'s width to be fixed as well, and to keep the paragraph's vertical-ish layout, make its display be `flex`.

```css
.row .right .content {
    padding-left: 20px;
    max-width: yy;
    display: flex;
}
```

where yy is the width of your paragraphs.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 105px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: -25px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#Cookieland {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #49403f;
}

body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.search-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 55px;
}

.search-input {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.search-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.search-button:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #49403f;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #49403f;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*Body section begins here*/

.banner-header {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/GMkdz66/cookiess.jpgg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  top: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.8s;
  animation: parallax linear;
  animation-timeline: scroll();
}

.banner-header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #92836c;
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: .1;
}

.cookie-heading {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #352000, 2px 2px 4px #352000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.description {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #352000;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes parallax {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}


/*Second row begins here*/

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px 30px;
  background-color: #636363;
  /*#f6f6f6*/
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 150px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.row .left {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row .left img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.row .right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row .right .content {
  padding-left: 20px;
  max-width: 40%;
  display: flex;
}

.row .right .content p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .row .right .content {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    width: 90%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Milk n' Cookies: Buy the best flavoured cookies!</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Header sections including navigation bar-->
  <header>
    <h1><a href="index.html" id="Cookieland">Milk n' Cookies</a></h1>

    <form class="search-container" action="#">
      <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search Cookies, flavours, recipes and more.">
      <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
    </form>

    <!--Navigation bar of the header-->
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!--Banner of the header section, it includes an about text with paragraph-->
  <section class="banner-header">
    <h2 class="cookie-heading">About us</h2>

    <p><span class="description">Welcome to Milk n' Cookies, where dreams are baked into reality! For over five decades,<br>our company has been delighting taste buds and warming hearts with our delectable array of cookies.</br> Established half a century ago, our journey began with a simple recipe and a passion for spreading joy</br> through irresistible treats. Today, we stand proudly as the epitome of excellence in the culinary world,</br> renowned as the best company globally for our unparalleled dedication to quality, innovation, and customer</br> satisfaction. With each bite of our scrumptious creations, customers embark on a journey of flavor</br> and nostalgia, making Milk n' Cookies  not just a brand but a cherished tradition in homes worldwide.</br> Join us as we continue to redefine sweetness for generations to come.</span></p>
  </section>

  <!--Second section, it includes an image and text-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg" alt="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/chocolate-chip-cookie-with-bite-taken-out-it_899894-8209.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus veritatis praesentium deleniti totam atque, corporis repellat? Doloremque inventore nostrum rerum nemo ullam assumenda architecto nesciunt? Nihil vero hic qui? Sequi?</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, culpa quasi omnis optio qui totam incidunt soluta quibusdam harum deleniti ut vel error tempora facere saepe a voluptas rem. Ut?</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam velit itaque tempore a, modi officia, autem, sint laudantium non animi nam onsequatur laborum aperiam. Culpa voluptatibus laborum natus illo eum.</p></div>
      

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have put your lorem ipsum inside the div with the content class inside the right part of your row, since I assumed that you merely misplaced the text.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've set 1000px width to the parent (.row)

```css
.row {width: 1000px;}
```

Try to change this value to 100%. It allows the div to take up the full width of its container.

```css
.row {width: 100%;}
```

Don't hesitate to inspect your project with the dev tools within your browser to see how DOM's elements behave with each other.

To open your browser's inspector: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (macOS)